# Assuming normal distribution with known samples

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose I have N samples(i.e random numbers 15 12 10 8 17 18.5 11 10).

I proceed to calculate the experimental mean and variance (xm = 12.69 and s = 3.73).

Can I assume that my samples are normally distributed? When can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Without any further information, you cannot assume anything about the distribution.

Comment: If your random numbers are chosen at random from interval $(10,20,$ then they are uniformly distributed, not normally distributed. But if you don't know the source of your $n = 7$ observations, it will be difficult to tell from what distribution they might have come. // For example, a Shapiro-Wilk test of normality can't rule out the possibility your 7 numbers may have come from a  normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a non parametric test...one way could be possible: you can apply Komogorov Smirnov Test.

Unfortunately this test can only be applied if the distribution you are going to fit is completely specified, say  you cannot use the sample mean and variance to complete your hypothesis but....**if you suspect** that your data come from a specified gaussian population, i.e.

$$X\sim N(13;12)$$

You can compare the empirical CDF with the Gaussian CDF finding

[image]

The KS test is the following

$$D(x)=\sup|S_x-F_x|=0.239$$

As the critical value at $\alpha=5\%$ in the KS table is $k=0.45427$ there are no reason to reject the hypothesis that your random sample comes from a Gaussian distribution.

---

Here is KS table taken from my first Statistics Textbook (with my original notes, 1984)

[image]